# TLE Need help in understanding the position vector

Tags: python, skyfield

I tried to take a TLE of an elliptical orbit and tried to calculate the position of the satellite for the next 16 hours. I understood that the position is an (x,y,z) vector which I can get in a kilometer(km) format from the Skyfield API.

When I feed it to the API, I get x-values of -22.78 km.
Can we have such low values of x ? Or am I missing something here ?

Here is my code

````
## Skyfield API reference!
##https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/earth-satellites.html
## Try with elliptical orbit TLE!

TLE = """1 42719U 17027A   22106.10583709 -.00000146  00000-0  00000-0 0  9996
2 42719  63.0826  96.1792 7054897 265.8018 253.5294  2.00598961 35833"""

L1, L2 = TLE.splitlines()

## Initialize the EarthSatellite object
tle_object = EarthSatellite(L1, L2)

print("TLE epoch :", tle_object.epoch.utc)

#For the next 16 hours, let us calculate the position and velocity of this 
#satellite.

for i in range(16):
    t = tle_object.epoch + timedelta(hours=i)
    #print (t.utc)
    posvec  = tle_object.at(t).position.km
    print(posvec)
    velovec  = tle_object.at(t).velocity.km_per_s
    #print(velovec)

```
````

Comment: x,y, & z could all be 0, just not at the same time

Comment: To be more specific, the x,y,z coordinates of a satellite could be any value, as long as not all three are 0 (it crashed).